# My project made in React js does NOT play in github, blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deployment, repository, github-pages

I have this problem and I think it has happened to many people.
I uploaded a react project to github pages, when I access to see the deploy, the screen appears blank, and the console tells me this, "main.jsx not load", I clarify that the file "main.jsx" is inside the repository.
[CONSOLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWEkj.jpg)
I would appreciate your answers, in the meantime I will try to deploy on vercel...

I still haven't managed to solve this, the file "main.jsx" is in the repository uploaded, but in the deploy it doesn't read it.

Comment: I have experienced this due to my app requiring to be at the root url and github pages adding a url prefix. Apologies I don't have time at the minute to double check this, but maybe add the url you are accessing your github page at, or an example of it if you want it to remain private.

Comment: It's been a year since I posted this haha.
i was very newbie, i just didn't make the build of the project, because github page is only for static pages, and i only uploaded the folder without making the respective build, and nowadays i would do it in vercel and not that way, newbie mistake but you learn :) now i'm with next js 14! success to all and thanks gavin for commenting